# How to access pagination values in kettle from pentaho cde?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pentaho-cde

I have a table component with data source attached to kettle transformation. 
Now, I want to implement server side pagination and access the parameters "pageStart" and "pageSize" set by pentaho in kettle transformation using getVariables. I have followed https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/143504-how-to-use-CDE-table-component-of-Paginate-server-side/ to set up server side paginate.
I do see the pageSize and pageStart parameters set in the post parameters in the doQuery in the network console but cannot access them in kettle transformation. Turns out I can only access parameters prefixed by "parameter" in the kettle transformation but not the ones without prefix "parameter", see the screenshot[image]

I can access the paramDateStart and paramDateEnd but not pageSize and pageStart in the transforamtion.

How can I achieve this so that I can only load certain data set based on parameters pageStart and pageSize from the server?

Comment: define variable, add parameter to the table component and add custom js to get the page size and pagestart and then call dashboard firechange

Comment: @Gaj I have defined the parameters and added them to the table component. could you please give more details on how to get pageSize and pageStart in a custom javascript?